# table over two columns in twocolumn mode

Tags: tables, floats, two-column

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption*{Results}
\begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} p{3cm} p{2cm} p{3cm} }  
\hline \\ [-0.3cm]
\textsc{Model} \\

parameters & Value $\pm$ $\theta$ &  p-values & range   \\ [0.5ex]
\hline 
\textbf{A} \\
\hspace{1cm} x & -0.1 $\pm$ 0.216  & 0.0000 & (-1.000, -0.560)  \\ 
\hspace{1cm} y & -2.1 $\pm$ 0.279  & 0.0000 & (-2.600, -1.500) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} z ($s^{-1}$)  & \hspace{0.15cm}0.1 $\pm$ 0.200 & 0.0001 & (0.400, 1.200) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} t1  & 1002  \\ 
\hline
\textbf{B} \\
\textbf{para1} \\
\hspace{1cm} b1 &  0.229 $\pm$ 1.104 & 0.800 & (-2.300, 1.900)  \\ 
\hspace{1cm} b2 & -0.753 $\pm$ 1.850  & 0.777  & (-4.100, 2.900)  \\ 
\hspace{1cm} b3 & -0.876 $\pm$ 1.863  & 0.5999  & (-4.000, 3.100) \\
\hspace{1cm} b4   & -0.6324 $\pm$ 1.176 & 0.5227  & (-3.200, 1.300) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} b5   & -0.123 $\pm$ 1.516 & 0.7882 & (-3.200, 2.600) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} b6  & -5.500 $\pm$ 1.522 & 0.0029 & (-7.800, -1.900) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} b7   & -0.600$\pm$ 1.120 & 0.6198 & (-2.700, 1.600)  \\ 

\textbf{para2} \\
\hspace{1cm} $a1 $  &   -1.00  $\pm$ 0.462 & 0.0356 &(-1.900, -0.100) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} a2   & -0.210 $\pm$ 0.092 & 0.0071 & (-0.400, -0.100) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} a3   &  \hspace{0.05cm} 1.10 $\pm$ 0.500 & 0.0099 & (0.600, 2.600) \\ 
\hspace{1cm}  a4    & -0.10 $\pm$ 0.059 & 0.0124 & (-0.200, -0.010) \\ 
\hspace{1cm} t2  &  20000      \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1 } 
\label{tab_1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Apologies for the rather lengthy code-it is needed to illustrate the current problem. The above code was taken from a [latex template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article). My problem is that the table inserted on the second page is too large for the page. This is due to the fact that the page is divided into two columns. I was just wondering if there was a way for me to make the table extend across the two columns without overlapping with the text. I'm guessing this documentclass automatically divides pages into two because I cant find any code that's responsible for this in the above. I know I could use `\begin{table}[p]` to move the table into a separate page but ideally I would like the table to be within the document rather than beyond bibliography.

Comment: Hi John and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll have a read and implement in future posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\begin{table*}
    ...
\end{table*}
```

to let a table span two columns.

And to be honest, not much of your code is "needed to illustrate the current problem". For example, it has nothing to do with the [SelfArx](https://github.com/Albex/Advanced_Architecture/blob/master/doc/report/SelfArx.cls) class you're using (and I first had to look for), and most of the other code you posted.

Here's a much more minimal version of your code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{Title}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Table caption}
    \begin{tabular}{csss}  
        \toprule
        \textsc{Model} \\
        Parameters & Value $\pm$ $\theta$ &  p-values & range\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{A} \\
        x & -0.1 $\pm$ 0.216  & 0.0000 & (-1.000, -0.560)  \\ 
        ...\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{B} \\
        \textbf{para1} \\
        b1 &  0.229 $\pm$ 1.104 & 0.800 & (-2.300, 1.900)  \\ 
        \ldots\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[5-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. How do I ensure the table stays within the document as opposed to at the end of the document?

Comment: Write your text until it's done. Then fiddle with the table placement. Your tables are so-called floats, which are placed based on the contents of your document by LaTeX. See this question regarding float placement: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text